# How to create a restart button for a quiz app?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a sample I got from the web. I want to create a restart button for the quiz. How am I suppose to do that? If possible, please include a Codepen demo too. Thank you !!

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Siyanda/pen/BLoVRL)

```
var all_questions = [{
  question_string: "What is my name?",
  choices: {
    correct: "James",
    wrong: ["John", "Bob", "Jeff"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Do you want to go to 1st question on restart?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Yes . First question to restart

Comment: Provide a demo please

Comment: please find my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Add below lines after submit button click event.

```
// Add listener for the restart button
$('#restart-button').click(function() {
  current_question_index = 0;
  change_question();
});
```

See the demo here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vivek257/pen/mdPOYON?editors=1111)

Comment: @Maximus Su if this resolve you problem please accept the answer else let me know what's the issue?